# How to change stored password in Skype4Business app?

Tags: applications, password

My domain password changed and the Skype4Businnes app on my phone started to complain about wrong credentials. How can the password in it be changed?

I searched everywhere and ended up reinstalling the app and entering the credentials on first start.

Comment: Isn't Skype4Business controlled through Office365? I think you need to change those passwords at the source. Check using your Office sign-in. Visit the MS Office Password Reset site for further details.

Comment: @wbogacz No, as it says, the password is stored in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting Skype4B:

- open the menu by swiping into the screen from left
- select "Sign Out" (last option)
- the login page appears
- there edit/delete the old password and enter the new one
- click the big arrow icon to sign in